# How to access child of a component in jest in a react/redux app

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I would like to test a component inside Connect in a Redux app:

```
this.component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Provider store={store}><Header path={this.path} /></Provider>);
```

I have no idea about how to access Header inside Provider since I can not step through in a debugger when running the jest from CLI.

When I tried to get a child inside Header

```
const path = findDOMNode(self.component.refs.pathElemSpan);
console.log("path="+path)
```

I got undefined on path

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `enzyme`, you have a bunch of nice selectors to navigate through your virtual DOM kingdom. :)

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/

A super simple test to access your component:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import Header from './header'

//... in your test
const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><Header path='foo' /></Provider>)
const header = wrapper.find(Header).first()
expect(header.exists()).toBe(true)
// you can even check out the props
expect(header.prop('path')).toBe('foo')
```

This example is using `mount` but you also have the option to do shallow rendering. I highly recommend you grab something to drink and read the docs a little. ;)

Comment: Why isn't this working in my Case? wrapper is returning back <Connect(Header) /> sorta component and wrapper.find(Header) is returning undefined...

Comment: @RegarBoy this answer is 5 years old, you may look to other alternatives now enzyme is kind of deprecated. react-testing-library is the most popular right now.

Comment: it isn't about who's more popular... I can't remove enzyme from our enterprise app on overnight...

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foo from '../components/Foo';


const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);

expect(wrapper.find(Foo)).to.have.lengthOf(1); //you can use this one
expect(wrapper.find('Foo')).to.have.lengthOf(1); //you can use this one as well
```

Comment: This answer appears to be using Enzyme's wrappers, which is automatically installed with jest. Make sure you note any extra dependencies your answer requires. If you are suggesting that the asker should use Enzyme, then please explain why.

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for this ?

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```