# How to inspect component when writing a unit test in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have this piece of unit test failing (2nd last line). How can I inspect the AnalysisList component to find out what is inside it after it has been instantiated by the test?

```js
test('should be one list', () => {
  const component = mount(
    <ValueAnalysisCard
      frequentValues={[]}
      rareValues={[]}
      objectTypeInstanceCount={objectTypeInstanceCount}
      derived={false}
      onSearch={onSearch}
    />
  );

  expect(component.find(AnalysisList)).toHaveLength(1);
  // expect(component.find(ListItem)).toHaveLength(1); // FAIL
  expect(component.find(LinkText)).toHaveLength(0);
});
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown why ListItem is expected to be there. In case ListItem is rendered not by ValueAnalysisCard directly, this isn't unit test and you're moving in wrong direction.

Comment: what type of renderer are you using?

Comment: This one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926856/863110

Comment: It is enzyme...

Comment: Add the code you want to test and the error information.